# iOS Swift YouTube Data API v3 Integration Crash App

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to implement YouTube Data API v3 in a newly created project for testing purpose. My main goal to upload video from app. I'm Following:

> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

step by step.

1. Created google OAuth2 client id.
2. Download and added GoogleService-Info.plist to my project.
3. Added reverse client id to my URL scheme.
4. Added all codes as mentioned by the Google.

I have checked several times that Client ID as showing in google console is same as CLIENT_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist file and also the bundle id.

But my crashing each times. It says:

> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000009] The GOOGLE_APP_ID either in the plist
>   file 'GoogleService-Info.plist' or the one set in the customized
>   options is invalid. If you are using the plist file, use the iOS
>   version of bundle identifier to download the file, and do not manually
>   edit the GOOGLE_APP_ID. You may change your app's bundle identifier to
>   'com.youtubeshare.youtubeshare'. Or you can download a new
>   configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
>
> 2019-06-27 18:52:16.255 Youtube-Test[7775] 
>   [Firebase/Core][I-COR000009] The GOOGLE_APP_ID either in the plist
>   file 'GoogleService-Info.plist' or the one set in the customized
>   options is invalid. If you are using the plist file, use the iOS
>   version of bundle identifier to download the file, and do not manually
>   edit the GOOGLE_APP_ID. You may change your app's bundle identifier to
>   'com.youtubeshare.youtubeshare'. Or you can download a new
>   configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
>
> Assertion failed: Error configuring Google services: Optional(Error
>   Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-3 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000032224c0 {Error Domain=com.firebase
>   Code=-1 "Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid
>   GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized
>   options." UserInfo={name=com.firebase.core,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Configuration fails. It may be caused by an
>   invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the
>   customized options.}}}): file
>   /Desktop/Youtube-Test/Youtube-Test/AppDelegate.swift, line 24
>
> 2019-06-27 18:52:16.257042+0530 Youtube-Test[7775:925765] Assertion
>   failed: Error configuring Google services: Optional(Error
>   Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-3 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000032224c0 {Error Domain=com.firebase
>   Code=-1 "Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid
>   GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized
>   options." UserInfo={name=com.firebase.core,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Configuration fails. It may be caused by an
>   invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the
>   customized options.}}}): file
>   /Desktop/Youtube-Test/Youtube-Test/AppDelegate.swift, line 24

[Please check the Xcode snapshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pemr.png)

Xcode: 10.2.1
iOS: 12.2

Did I mistaken anything here? Kindly help me out from here.

If you need any other information from my end, kindly feel free to add a comment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I got the answer. That the app which is created from https://console.developer.google.com, that must be link with Firebase (https://console.firebase.google.com) app. And the plist need to download from

> Firebase console -> Project Overview -> Project Settings -> Download
>   GoogleService-Info.plist

. This file should be added in the project bundle.